# AWS S3: how to list object by tags

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, tags, aws-sdk

I created objects with tag with following snippet of code

```
PutObjectRequest putRequest = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, keyName, new File(filePath)); 
List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<Tag>();
tags.add(new Tag("Key1", "Value1"));
tags.add(new Tag("Key2", "Value2"));
putRequest.setTagging(new ObjectTagging(tags));
PutObjectResult putResult = s3client.putObject(putRequest);
```

I get list of objects with code

```
s3client.listObjectsV2(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
   else     console.log(data);  
}
```

My question:

how to get list of objects filtered by tags ?

If impossible to filter by tag, what is the purpose of tag that S3 introduced?

Comment: See [Difference between object tags and metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42146207/1695906) for an explanation of the usefulness of tags.  They are not accessible by querying or scanning.

Comment: Hi, so what is the best practice to categorise the S3 objects ? so that it's easy to filter the list of S3 object

Comment: An external database is the best way.

Comment: Hi Michael, could you please to make it clearer? an external db means using SQL based db (like MySql, or Postgresql, ...)

Comment: Any external db that can be queried.  I use RDS/MariaDB in an (as yet unreleased) product that uses S3 event notifications to automatically index objects by keys, tags, and metadata.  You could also use DynamoDB with global secondary indexes.

Comment: I found this blog to have a good answer for you: https://analyticshut.com/list-s3-buckets-using-python-aws-cli/