# How to upload to AWS S3 with Object Tagging

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

Is there a way to upload file to AWS S3 with Tags(not add Tags to an existing File/Object in S3). I need to have the file appear in S3 with my Tags , ie in a single API call.

I need this because I use a Lambda Function (that uses these S3 object Tags) is triggered by S3 ObjectCreation

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can inform the `Tagging` attribute on the `put` operation.

Here's an example using `Boto3`:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('s3')

client.put_object(
    Bucket='bucket', 
    Key='key',
    Body='bytes', 
    Tagging='Key1=Value1'
)
```

As per the [docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object), the `Tagging` attribute  must be encoded as URL Query parameters. (For example, "Key1=Value1")

> Tagging — (String) The tag-set for the object. The tag-set must be
>   encoded as URL Query parameters. (For example, `"Key1=Value1"`)

**EDIT**: I only noticed the `boto3` tag after a while, so I edited my answer to match boto3's way of doing it accordingly.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. This also works with other methods, like upload_fileobj with the parameter `ExtraArgs`.

Comment: Use `&` as a delimiter between tag values like `"Key1=Value1"&"Key2=Value2"`. If you need to upload without a value its just `"Key1&Key2&Key3"`.

Comment: There's a little quoting issue in the above example. It should look like this: `Tagging='key1=value1&key2=value2'`.

Answer (score 8):

`Tagging` directive is now supported by [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/customizations/s3.html#boto3.s3.transfer.TransferConfig). You can do the following to add tags if you are using `upload_file()`

```
import boto3

from urllib import parse

s3 = boto3.client("s3")

tags = {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}

s3.upload_file(
    "file_path",
    "bucket",
    "key",
    ExtraArgs={"Tagging": parse.urlencode(tags)},
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're uploading a file using `client.upload_file()` or other methods that have the `ExtraArgs` parameter, <del>you specify the tags differently</del> you need to add *tags* in a separate request. You can add metadata as follows, but this is not the same thing. For an explanation of the difference, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42126348/7830612):

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('s3')

client.upload_file(
    Filename=path_to_your_file,
    Bucket='bucket', 
    Key='key',
    ExtraArgs={"Metadata": {"mykey": "myvalue"}}
)
```

There's an example of this on the [S3 docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.42/guide/s3.html), but <del>you have to know that "metadata" corresponds to tags</del> be aware that metadata is not exactly the same thing as tags though it can function similarly.

```
s3.upload_file(
    "tmp.txt", "bucket-name", "key-name",
    ExtraArgs={"Metadata": {"mykey": "myvalue"}}
)
```