# AWS Boto3 S3 copy not copying tags

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3

I have a function which which changes the storage class of an S3 object. The function works except tags are ***not*** being copied

```py
        def to_deep_archive(s3_key):
        '''
        Set the storage to DEEP_ARCHIVE
        Copied from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39309846/how-to-change-storage-class-of-existing-key-via-boto3
        '''
        s3 = boto3.client('s3')

        # Source data to move to DEEP_ARCHIVE
        copy_source = {
                'Bucket' : BUCKET,
                'Key' : s3_key
        }

        # TODO : encryption
        # convert to DEEP_ARCHIVE by copying
        s3.copy(
                copy_source,
                BUCKET,
                s3_key,
                ExtraArgs = {
                        'StorageClass' : 'DEEP_ARCHIVE',
                        'MetadataDirective' : 'COPY',
                        'TaggingDirective' : 'COPY',
                        'ServerSideEncryption' : 'AES256'
                }
        )
```

There was no exception thrown. My role policy looks something like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObjectTagging",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectTagging",
                "s3:PutObjectTagging",
                "s3:ReplicateTags"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

My bucket policy looks like this:

```
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1492757001621",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::my_account:role/my_role"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectTagging",
                "s3:PutObjectTagging",
                "s3:DeleteObjectTagging",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ReplicateTags"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket"
            ]
        }
```

Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Have you tried [copy_object](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.copy_object) instead of simple `copy`? The `copy_object` has the explicit options for the tags ` TaggingDirective='COPY'|'REPLACE',`

Comment: @Marcin I believe copy_object has a limitation which restrict it to objects <= 5GB, see https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/1715. This is unfortunate as there are objects in my bucket that have size greater than 5GB.

Comment: Yes, because its not multi part. What about replicating the bucket to new a bucket with new storage class? Then you delete the old bucket.

Comment: An alternative is to use [Amazon S3 Object Lifecycle Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html) to change the Storage Class after a given time period. I would expect that tags would remain intact.

Answer (score 3):

I've found an interesting discrepancy in how `s3.copy()` handles the `Tagging` and `TaggingDirective` extra arguments.

As per the source code of [s3transfer/copies.py](https://github.com/boto/s3transfer/blob/develop/s3transfer/copies.py), which seems to perform the `s3.copy()`,  the underlying implementation depends on the object's size. If it exceeds a certain `multipart_threshold`, then it's uploaded using `s3_client.upload_part_copy()`. If it's below the threshold, it's uploaded using the ordinary `s3_client.copy_object()`, which has a file size limit of 5GB. From the [copy_object](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.copy_object) docs:

> You create a copy of your object up to 5 GB in size in a single atomic action using this API. However, to copy an object greater than 5 GB, you must use the multipart upload Upload Part - Copy (UploadPartCopy) API.

Unfortunately, the `Tagging` and `TaggingDirective` arguments are supported by `copy_object()` but not by `upload_part_copy()`. See the latter's documentation [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_part_copy). Therefore, `TaggingDirective` is explicitly *blacklisted* as an argument to exclude when submitting the `upload_part_copy()` request, but the same is not performed for `copy_object()`, where the argument, along with `Tagging`, is provided.

In summary, both tagging `ExtraArgs` seem as though they should work for small files, but not for large ones. Therefore, I'm reverting to performing a subsequent `put_object_tagging()` call after the copy, which is unfortunate due to the additional API call and the delay between copy and tagging.

Comment: Actually you can directly copy tagging, but you'll need one more API to call fetch it as well; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/68000677/1374078

Answer (score 0):

You can use copy object and `TaggingDirective='COPY'` to copy s3 objects with tags.

```py
response = s3.copy_object(
                    Bucket='destination bucket',
                    CopySource={'Bucket': 'source bucket',
                                'Key': object["Key"]},
                    Key=object["Key"],
                    TaggingDirective='COPY'
                )
```